# Oracle Question for Access to a new view on an existing OWNER

Tags: oracle

We have a requirement to add a new view to an existing schema/owner. The schema currently has few objects tables/indexes, we want to give only select access to the new view, and not any access to existing objects tables/indexes.

Is there a way to restrict at login for that schema/owner, to only select from one view, and not from rest of the objects owned by the schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you log in as the owner then there is no way to restrict access. The owner can always see, update, alter, or drop objects in its schema. Access can only be controlled when users connect as someone *other* than the schema owner. In general, connecting as the owner is considered extremely insecure.